# Windows 10: Fix the default new folder view customization

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, desktop-customization, user-folders

I want to set the default new folder view to `Documents`, whatever its contents.

I have set all drives and subfolders in the `"optimize this folder for"`  to view as `Documents`, and applied it to all folders, however when I create a new folder (in the Desktop especially) and add some images to it, the folder view changes to `Pictures`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Where and how are you creating the folder?

Comment: Thanks @KeithMiller for the reply.  In the Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explorer indexes saved folder views by their full namespace path in the BagMRU key. So a folder on the Destkop can have different views saved for:

- `FolderName`
- `This PC\Desktop\FolderName`
- `This PC\C:\Users\<UserProfileFolder>\Desktop\FolderName`

When `Also apply this template to all subfolders` is selected from a folder's `Properties` dialog, a subkey named `Inherit` is created under the folder's PropertyBag in the registry.

When a folder is displayed in Explorer for the first time, all its *namespace* ancestors, not file system ancestors are checked for an `Inherit` subkey. If found, that will override both content-sniffing and any FolderType specified in a `desktop.ini` file.

The fun (and useful) fact revealed by Process Monitor is that even though there is no way to set inheritance through the UI for **This PC**, the *root/virtual* **Desktop**, and other non-filesytem locations, **Explorer** still checks their PropertyBags for the `Inherit` subkey. So creating an `Inherit` subkey for the rooted Desktop will govern the FolderType of folders created on the Desktop, as well as all other file system folders, including the folders under **This PC**, with the annoying exception of `Downloads`. Search results and Libraries are virtual folders and not affected by this setting.

To set Inheritance for the rooted Desktop:

1. Ensure a PropertyBag for the view of the rooted Desktop exists by viewing and then closing in **Explorer**. To navigate to the rooted Desktop:

   - From **This PC** or **Quick Access**, click the `Up` arrow to the left of the **Explorer** Address bar.
   - copy and paste the commannd `shell:Desktop` into the **Explorer** Address bar or a `Run` dialog.
2. Determine the bag number by checking the registry alue `NodeSlot` under the key:
   `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU`
   Using:

   - **PowerShell**:

     ```
       (gp 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU').NodeSlot
     ```
   - **Registry Editor**:
     [image]
3. Create the registry key:

   - `HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\<Bag#>\Shell\Inherit` and within it two REG_SZ types:

     - `FolderType` with a value of `Documents`
     - `SniffedFolderType` with a value of `Documents`

   **PowerShell** (substitute actual Bag # in first line, then paste entire block into **PowerShell**):

   ```
   $BagNum = <your bag #>
   $Path   = ( mkdir "HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\$BagNum\Shell\Inherit" -Force ).FullName
   'FolderType' , 'SniffedFolderType' | ForEach {
       New-ItemProperty $Path $_ -Value 'Documents' | out-null
   }
   ```

   Reg File Template (substitute bag # in key path):

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\<Bag#>\Shell\Inherit]
   "FolderType"="Documents"
   "SniffedFolderType"="Documents"
   ```

The above is a great way to quickly test/verify the edit is working. But if you've been twarted by content-sniffing and other default behaviors in the past and consistency is your goal, it's best to start with a "clean" slate --- deleting previously saved folder views to ensure your desired view is applied accross the board. This is acccomplished by:

1. Deleting the `BagMRU` and `Bags` keys.
2. Signing out and back in or re-starting the Shell to wipe out any cached view info.

The followinng **PowerShell** will do that as well as open & close Explorer directly to the Desktop --- making the Desktop Bag #1. It will then create the `INherit` key and its values.

```
Set-Location 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell'
'BagMRU' , 'Bags' | Remove-Item -Recurse
Get-Process explorer | Stop-Process
Sleep 5
($Shell = New-Object -com shell.application).Open("shell:Desktop")
Sleep 5
@($Shell.Windows()).Quit()
Sleep 5
$Path  = (mkdir 'Bags\1\Shell\Inherit' -Force).FullNName

'FolderType' , 'SniffedFolderType' | ForEach {
    New-ItemProperty $Path $_ -Value 'Documents' | out-null
}
```